# "The security group does not exist" when setting Elastic Beanstalk EC2 security group with Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-security-group

As the title goes, I have this Terraform file:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "database" {
  name = "my-database"
}

resource "aws_elastic_beanstalk_environment" "default" {
  # ...

  setting {
    namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
    name      = "SecurityGroups"
    value     = aws_security_group.database.id
  }
}
```

However, when I run `terraform apply`, I get the following error:

> Error: updating Elastic Beanstalk Environment (e-7mdzvujjfx): ConfigurationValidationException: Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: 'sg-0beb6502be9e607bf' (Namespace: 'aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration', OptionName: 'SecurityGroups'): The security group 'sg-0beb6502be9e607bf' does not exist

…but the security group **does** exist and it has the exact same ID.

Answer (score 0):

I manually changed the security group via the AWS console and when the Terraform state refreshed, I noticed the following in `terraform.tfstate`:

```json
...
{
  "name": "SecurityGroups",
  "namespace": "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration",
  "resource": "",
  "value": "my-database"
},
...
```

It appears that the setting expects the security group *name*, rather than ID.

If I change my Terraform config to use the name, everything works out:

```
setting {
  namespace = "aws:autoscaling:launchconfiguration"
  name      = "SecurityGroups"
  value     = aws_security_group.database.name
  # ----------------- `name`, not `id` ---^^^^
}
```